# How to resolve java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII

Tags: java-security

I have one test named test_PBE_Triple_DES, here I am using `PBE_DES3_CBC_SHA1_ALGORITHM` to decode the encrypted password but whenever I try to execute it I get an error saying that the password is not ascii.

I have provided the stacktrace below.

```
com.tibco.security.AXSecurityException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII
    at com.tibco.security.providers.CryptoVendorImpl_j2se.rename(CryptoVendorImpl_j2se.java:205)
    at com.tibco.security.Crypto.rename(Crypto.java:59)
    at com.tibco.security.TestPassword.test_PBE_Triple_DES(TestPassword.java:105)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKey.<init>(PBEKey.java:64)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKeyFactory.engineGenerateSecret(PBEKeyFactory.java:219)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:330)
    at com.tibco.security.providers.CryptoVendorImpl_j2se.rename(CryptoVendorImpl_j2se.java:161)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661644/java-encryption-setup-fails-with-invalidkeyspecexception

Comment: Yes, But the combination of algorithm and key used in the post you suggested is different. Can you tell me why this type of error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this, I was reading the password from a file on the system and it had a newline automatically appended at the end of it it by vim. After I turned off the feature off in vim it worked fine.

Here's how to disable new line.
[How to stop VIM from adding a newline at end of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050640/how-to-stop-vim-from-adding-a-newline-at-end-of-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think the password must be number. Ex: 1247980375091875908431789013789013578901759.
Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, In my case there was new line character was appended. Just added trim method and it got resolved

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than a new answer.